# How to determine an object in a given object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an Object-

```
var obj = { 
    name : 'John',
    contact : { 
           address : 'xyz',
           phone : 555
    }
}
```

Now when I loop through this object

```
for (let key in obj) {
     console.log(typeof key);
}
```

In Both cases I get type of 'string'.
So is there any way to get contact value as an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `key` actually contains "name" and "contact" strings.

If you want to detect type of a value contained in `contact` property, you need to access it this way:

```
typeof obj[key]
```

Demo:

```js
var obj = { 
  name : 'John',
  contact : { 
   address : 'xyz',
   phone : 555
  }
}

for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(key + " (key is " + typeof key + ", value is " + typeof obj[key] + "):");
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to address the value of the property with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
console.log(typeof obj[key]);
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, you get always `'string'`, because keys of objects are strings.

```js
var obj = { name : 'John', contact : { address : 'xyz', phone : 555 } };

for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(typeof obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find type of key whereas you should find type of value like, 
**typeof obj[key]**

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without any looping, if you know the key of the property you want:

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'John',
  contact: {
    address: 'xyz',
    phone: 555
  }
};

console.log(obj.contact);
console.log(obj["contact"]);
console.log(typeof obj.contact);
console.log(typeof obj["contact"]);
```

When using a loop, `"contact"` turns into a variable. This means you access the property like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]); // key === "contact"
}
```

instead of this:

```
obj["contact"]
```

You should also note the difference between `obj.key` and `obj[key]`:

```js
var obj = {
  key: "this_is_a_key",
  foo: "this_is_a_foo"
};

var key = "foo";
console.log(obj.key); // returns the "key" property
console.log(obj[key]); // returns the "foo" property because the key variable holds "foo"
```